# Проверить условие заполнения двух коллекций

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который сохраняет рецепт блюда в БД. Кроме самого рецепта, есть еще две коллекции (ingredientsList, recipeStepsList), которые содержат ингредиенты и шаги, описывающие последовательность готовки блюда.

Пользователь может добавить несколько шагов или категорий и заполнить каждый шаг. Что-то не могу сообразить как реализовать проверку условия заполнены ли все добавленные шаги или ингредиенты рецепта. Делаю так как описано ниже, но после заполнения всех шагов, дальше проверка не идет.

А нужно чтобы обе коллекции проверялись так: Если список шагов или ингредиентов непустой, то проверять описание каждого шага/ингредиента. И если шаг или ингредиент пустой, то выводить сообщение чтобы заполнили, если есть описание, идем дальше.

```
private void saveRecipe() {
    peremRecipeTitle = recipeTitle.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeDescription = recipeDescription.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeTags = recipeTags.getText().toString();
    peremRecipePreparationTime = recipePreparationTime.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeCookTime = recipeCookTime.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeDownTime = recipeDownTime.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeAllTime = recipeAllTime.getText().toString();
    peremRecipePortions = recipePortions.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeNutritionalValue = recipeNutritionalValue.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeDishes = recipeDishes.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeNations = recipeNations.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeComments = recipeComments.getText().toString();
    peremRecipeSource = recipeSource.getText().toString();

    Recipe recipe = new Recipe(
            peremRecipeTitle
            ,peremRecipeDescription
            ,categoryID
            ,peremRecipeTags
            ,peremRecipePreparationTime
            ,peremRecipeCookTime
            ,peremRecipeDownTime
            ,peremRecipeAllTime
            ,peremRecipePortions
            ,peremRecipeNutritionalValue
            ,peremRecipeDishes
            ,peremRecipeNations
            ,peremRecipeComments
            ,peremRecipeSource
            ,0
            ,peremRecipeImage
    );

    if (peremRecipeTitle.equals("")) { 
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Заполните название", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (peremRecipeDescription.equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Заполните описание", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if (categoryID == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Выберите категорию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if(recipeStepList.size() != 0) { //Если список, описывающий шаги не пустой
        for (int i = 0; i < recipeStepList.size(); i++) { //то для каждого шага 
            if (recipeStepList.get(i).getStepDescription().equals("")) { //проверяем заполнено ли его описание
                Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Введите описание шага или шагов", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } else if (ingredientList.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ingredientList.size(); i++) {
            if (ingredientList.get(i).getName().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Введите все ингредиенты", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    } else { 
        //Сохраняем рецепт в БД

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе условия немножко неверные. Так получилось, потому что вы сложили все в одну кучу и даже просто читая код, нельзя быстро понять что происходит. Нет декомпозиции задачи.
Я бы порекомендовал выделить отдельные функции валидации:

```
boolean validateRecipeRequireFields(Recipe recipe) {
    if (recipe.getRecipeTitle().equals("")) { 
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Заполните название", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (recipe.getRecipeDescription().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Заполните описание", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    } else if (recipe.getCategoryID() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Выберите категорию", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

boolean validateRecipeSteps(List<?> recipeStepList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < recipeStepList.size(); i++) { //то для каждого шага 
        if (recipeStepList.get(i).getStepDescription().equals("")) { //проверяем заполнено ли его описание
            Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Введите описание шага или шагов", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

boolean validateIngredients(List<?> ingredientList) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ingredientList.size(); i++) {
        if (ingredientList.get(i).getName().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(AddRecipeActivity.this, "Введите все ингредиенты", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Далее в методе сохранения использовать эти функции:

```
Recipe recipe = new Recipe
...
if (validateRecipeRequireFields(recipe) 
  && validateRecipeSteps(recipeStepList)
  && validateIngredients(ingredientList)
  ){
  //Сохраняем рецепт в БД
}
```

Comment: Действительно так лучше спасибо большое.